# Any codes that does clear color completely for powerpoint shape?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
'I have tried to apply a color by vba with this code to a shape
.Fill.ForeCorlor.RGB = RGB(250, 0, 0)

'but soon I realize this color stay in memory* even though I tried to clear it with
.Fill.Transparency = 0.5 'Or
.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

'I do not want to use .Fill.ForeColor.TGB = RBB(255, 255, 255) 
 to set another color as it may overlay and block other content
```

*In memory: I mean when I applied a color to a shape and try to clear it with the above method, The next time I target shape with RGB(230,0,0), this shape that I thought has been previously set the color and clear still get targeted.

Appreciate for any help on this
G

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "this shape that I thought has been previously set the color and clear still get targeted."

Comment: Thanks Williams for your response, 
Let me elaborate clearer for what I want to do
Step 1: I want to target all the shape in powerpoint that are Red color i.e (250 , 0 , 0) then use something like if it's red, move them somewhere in the slide, change font to Arial for example, after that remove the fill 

Step 2: Then in future when use the same code again to move things around, the shape that I thought I have previous removed the fill by .Fill.Visible = msoFalse still get moved even though I din't set it as Red. 

Step 3: So what I'm trying to seek is away to clear the color completely.

Comment: So set the fill to white (or any other color) and then set the visibility to false?

Comment: If you want to find a shape again, Tag it ... .Tags.Add "MyTagName", "MyTagValue"  Later you can search through all the shapes on a slide looking for one whose .Tags("MyTagName") = "MyTagValue"